# Emails keep being sent from Example <hello@example.com>

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

Already read a lot and even did php artisan config:clear
Checked thourghout all files and hello@example.com is nowhere.

It works from local w/o problems.

Also, have another app in plain PHP that uses PHPMailer and this issue does not happen so I don't think it would be something related to the server.

Any help appreciated hence this script is only waiting this issue to be solved so it can be live.

---

> **UPDATE:** The issue was with the mail server. We changed the mail server
>   to a different machine but didn't configure completely the DNS.
>
> Thanks to both for answering.

Comment: What does your .env file look like on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)**First of all you have to set the environment variable in .env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mail.abc.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@abc.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=abc123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

2) **Then import this in your controller,**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

3)  **Then add this function in your controller,**

```
public function basic_email() {
  $data = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi");
  Mail::send(['text'=>'mail'], $data, function($message) {
        $message->from('info@abc.com');
        $message->subject('Testing');
        $message->to('abc@gmail.com'); 
 echo "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
    });
```

4) I hope this helped you.

Comment: @iPublicisCOM happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Email address is configured in config/mail.php file

```
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

but how you can see it is using environment vars configured in .env in root directory

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@blabla.com.ar
MAIL_FROM_NAME="San Marino Pastas"
```

Remeber if you are using artisan serve or queue listining restart the services to take the new config.

Please try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: "Remeber if you are using artisan serve or queue listining restart the services to take the new config." Excellent tip!